# Generalization of "Characteristic subgroup of a normal subgroup is normal"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $K\leq H \leq G$. Prove that if $A\subseteq Aut(G)$, $H$ is $A$-invariant subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is a characteristic subgroup of $H$, then $K$ is an $A$-invariant subgroup of $G$.

Let $\alpha\in A$. We want to show that $\alpha(K)\subseteq K$.
Since $H$ is $A$-invariant subgroup of $G$, we have $\alpha(H)\subseteq H$.
So the usual way is to restrict $\alpha$ to form an automorphism of $H$.
But I only know that $\alpha$ is 1-1 and I cannot make sure that $\alpha(H)=H$.
Also, since $A$ is not a subgroup of $Aut(G)$, I do not know that whether $\alpha^{-1}\in A$.

Remark:
$H$ is an $A$-invariant subgroup of $G$ if $\alpha(h)\in H$ for every $\alpha\in A$ and $h\in H$.

Comment: I am surprised that this is true, although I cannot immediately think of a counterexample. Are you sure you have the definition of $A$-invariant right? If you has asked me what it meant I would have said it meant $\alpha(H) = H$ for all $\alpha \in A$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes. And this is in fact question 93 in the book A Course on Group Theory by John S. Rose. (page 40)

Comment: $\alpha $ bieng 1-1 implies that $\alpha (H)= H$ from first isomorphism theorem: $H/ker(\alpha) \cong \alpha(H)$

Comment: @Sheve By first isomorphism theorem, we can only get $\alpha(H)\cong H$.

Comment: I think this is a mistake by the author. The other exercises I looked at are reasonably straightforward. The following one Question 94 is starred byut is not particularly difficult.